# Access Vertica with kerberos in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, kerberos, vertica

I am running PySpark 2 & trying to access data from Vertica authenticated by kerberos.

I am using following mechanism with JDBC driver:

```
# PySpark python 3.5
krb_url = "jdbc:vertica://vertica.example.net:5433/DB;" + \
"integratedSecurity=true;authenticationSchema=JavaKeberos;principal=userx;keytab=/home/userx/userx.keytab;"

query = " (SELECT id FROM schema.table limit 10) as t1"

kdf = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
    .option("driver", "com.vertica.jdbc.Driver") \
    .option("url", krb_url) \
    .option("dbtable", query) \
    .load()
```

However,  I'm getting following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o68.load.
: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation.<init>(JDBCRelation.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:146)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```